# Require specific version of CocoaPods to be installed form Podfile

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podspec

In our project we want to ensure that all developers are using the same version of CocoaPods by adding a version verification within the Podfile as a prerequisite check when a developer attempts to perform *pod install* or *pod update*.

Is it possible to achieve this from within the Podfile?

Comment: You can't do that, but you can write a script who will check the installed version of cocoapod and display a warning or other thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you'll need to create a Gemfile, which is like a Podfile for RubyGems, which CocoaPods is distributed as. There is a guide to do this for CocoaPods [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/a-gemfile.html). Mainly you'll create a Gemfile with something like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'cocoapods', '~> 0.38.2'
```

Then you can install your specified version with `bundle install`. This will install the same version on all developer's machines. After that you'll run `bundle exec pod install` to make sure that `pod install` is run by the version specified in your Gemfile (which may not be the case if the user has multiple version of CocoaPods installed).

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect!